# why do java applet is not widely used

Tags: java

we know the purpose of java applet, to bring some binary programs into our browsers safely,
and also bring rich user interface to the client,

but why it didnt succeed? 
and Adobe Flash instead ruled the world of RIA

Answer (score 3):

For one, Flash has a much faster startup time than Java. Whenever I see a Java applet nowadays the first thing I notice is 5 seconds of coffee cup telling me to wait until Java boots up. Not nice.

Then Flash offers much easier access to many simple things, like animations, effects, sound and video, etc. that might be there in applets but much more cumbersome to use. A side effect of this is probably that many Flash developers didn't come from the software development but the design world.

Comment: Not to mention the client is a lot smaller and made it easier to distribute to people with slow connections.

Comment: ... end evolves much more rapidly :-)